# Context Free Grammars - LR(0) DFA

Tags: context-free-grammar, finite-automata, dfa, formal-languages

I need some help with constructing a LR(0) DFA for a Context Free Grammar.

```
S -> A
A -> aaAb | B
B -> aBb | e
```

This is what I have:

**State**

```
{ S -> .A
  A -> .aaAb
  A -> .B
  B -> .aBb
  B -> .e
}
```

Then I have an arrow labeled `a` to:

**State**

```
    { A-> a.aAb
      B-> a.Bb
      B-> .aBb
      B -> .e }
```

And from this state, an arrow labeled `a` to:

**State:**

```
    { A ->  aa.Ab
      A -> .aaAb
      A -> .B
      B -> .aBb
      B -> a.Bb
      B -> .e   }
```

This is where my problem starts. As you can see, I get two arrows labeled `B` from this state because I have:

```
B -> .B
b -> a.Bb
```

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: What makes you think this is a problem? (Also, it might help to label your "state-items" with the state they originate from, e.g. `A->a.Ab` **from 0**)

Comment: Yes you are right, it isn't a problem :) I was just stupid :P Thank you

Comment: You might want to play with this tool -- http://mdaines.github.com/grammophone/ (source is here: https://github.com/mdaines/grammophone). You can input a grammar, an the webapp will generate parsing tables and automatons for LR-parsers. Pretty neat.